# Change part of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

i've got the popup window, where i can change icon by attribute:

```
$(this).attr('class', popup.find('i').attr('icon-class'));
```

and html of this element:

```
<i class="small icon-adjustments"></i>
```

but you can see that i have **two classes** `small` and `icon-adjustments` that change.

The problem is when i change class, my script remove `small` class too. how i can change only the second part of class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to change a part of the `className` attribute is by using jQuery:

```
$(this).removeClass('icon-adjustments').addClass('new-class-name')
```

---

But there are also some other methods.

For instance, you can use `replace`:

```
this.className.replace('icon-adjustments', 'new-class-name')
```

or split the `className` attribute by space and then replace the nth element:

```
var names = this.className.split(' ')
names[1] = 'new-class-name'
this.className = names.join(' ')
```

If you only want to remove a part of the class name, just pass an empty string instead.

A method that abstracts this code might look like:

```
function replaceClass(element, oldClass, newClass) {
    var names = element.className.split(' ')
    var i, len;

    for (i = 0, len = names.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (names[i] === oldClass) {
            names[i] = newClass;
        }
    }

    element.className = names.join(' ')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w3hL0h9d/

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery addclass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) instead of attr

```
$(this).addClass(popup.find('i').attr('icon-class'));
```

Comment: if i use addClass,like `$(this).addClass(popup.find('i').attr('icon-class'));` previous class doesn't removed, they will are added indefinitely

Comment: could you provide a fiddle to figure out your issue

Comment: i use backbone for this code and i will write fiddle so long, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

You might use [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/), before using the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/). You might need to check if a certain class exist by using [.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) in the beginning.